# how to use Fragment in ListView cell?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, baseadapter

I have a fragment showing product detail.
Products detail coming from server in array.
I want to show that product details in fragment and that fragment should be adapted to ListView.

```
Fragment in ListView
```

I found a lot but unable to find solution.
Please help me.

Comment: instead of that you can create different type of items, fragment is not a good idea!

Comment: why not as item ? why use fragment ? from my expirience it causes a lot of problems

Comment: But this is the client requirement to use fragment

Comment: It's irrational to use fragments inside of a ListView. If you need the fragment somewhere else also, better explain the situation and we will give you ideas.

Comment: i don't think the client will ever know the diffrence , sometimes they just use words they know , you can use recyclerview and do animations and such , you can let him know that using fragments in a listview will be awfull , i did it once and had to write it all from the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragment inside list view is practically possible but it will only visible in first cell where given containerId is found.

```
fTransaction.replace(containerId, fragment);
```

> You can use but can't reuse.